# What is best approach to add a Counter in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I want to count Order placed after My Module installation that counter can be reset By User and have Custom Starting Value and Steps Bases On Config Value

I am thinking of creating New Config Feild

If anyone has a better suggestion please share with me

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your task completely it is quite easily done like this:

1. Create a system configuration that have some fields, for example: starting value, step. (you can set starting value here to reset counter) or whatever you need to fit your task.
2. Create an observer (event: sales_order_save_after_commit)
3. This observer would take my custom configuration and do all your calculations, after that just save a result to your system config value.
4. Done

Comment: should I create a counter is system configurations?

Comment: You can create counter just as a simple system configuration, if you want to see it, you can make a field that is read only and show it in the admin.
If this is a simple functionality, I would keep it in the system configuration values with all other values. :)

Comment: I don't want to see that field in system.xml so I added type="hidden" but now it's not saving in core_condig_data

Comment: Your counter will be increased in the observer not in the admin. Add it to the admin if you want to to see it. Remember that there is more ways to work with system configuration.